# Maps from an open set to $\Bbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ from $V\to\Bbb{C}$ be a biholomorphism, where $V$ is an open subset of $\Bbb{C}$. Then how to show that $V=\Bbb{C}$. I solved it when $V$ is bounded using Liouville Theorem. What will happen if $V$ is unbounded? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Picard's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) and the fact that $V\cong \Bbb C$ as topological spaces.